# How to get p-value for fixed-effects by model comparsion?

Tags: r, p-value, lme4-nlme

I am doing linear mixed model using lme4. According to Winter (2013, http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf), as the new version of R does not give p-values due to inconclusion of degree of freedom, p-values of mixed models can be derived from model comparison. From the examples on page 12, he suggested to construct the null model:

```
politeness.null=lmer (frequency ~ gender + (1|subject) + (1|scenario), data=politeness, REML=FALSE)
```

Then add the fixed effect that we are interested in:

```
politeness.null=lmer (frequency ~ attitude + gender + (1|subject) + (1|scenario), data=politeness, REML=FALSE)
```

And then the p-values of attitude can be given from

```
anova(politeness.null,politeness.model)
```

However, in my case, I have 3-way interaction: color*sex*food, and when I run the model I have 17 layers of fixed effects, such as white (compare to red), blue (compared to red), white:male(compared to female), etc.

Then my question is how I can get p-values for all these fixed effects? I am not sure if I should have some fixed effects that I am not interested in first:

```
lmer1=lmer (duration ~ action + (1|subject) + (1|repetition), data=data.frame, REML=FALSE)
```

Then add:

```
lmer1=lmer (duration ~ action + color + (1|subject) + (1|repetition), data=data.frame, REML=FALSE)
```

Then add:

```
lmer1=lmer (duration ~ action + color + sex + (1|subject) + (1|repetition), data=data.frame, REML=FALSE)
```

or

```
lmer1=lmer (duration ~ action + color*sex + (1|subject) + (1|repetition), data=data.frame, REML=FALSE)
```

or

```
lmer1=lmer (duration ~ action + sex + (1|subject) + (1|repetition), data=data.frame, REML=FALSE)
```

Anyone can help me about this? or is there any other ways to get p-values easier than model comparison?

Comment: You might be interested in `help("pvalues")`. However, a p-value is nothing without a hypothesis. You should clearly state the hypothesis you want to test.

Comment: My hypothesis is the duration is different in different colors. (and I also would like to see if there are any effects in color and other factors, that's why I do the interaction).

Comment: So, why is model comparison not sufficient to answer this?

Comment: Because I am not sure if I should fit each level of fixed factors one at a time, or adding them all once. For example, should I add only sex to the null model to find the p value of sex? And how about sex*color, should I add this interaction to the null model to get p value? I am asking because I think the p-values will also change according to the number of factors adding. So in my opinion, having both sex and sex*color might yield different p-values. Am I right?